# layoutSubviews or constraints?

Tags: swift, custom-controls

I'm new to programming with Xcode (and Obj-C or Swift) and my question is:

Are there any disadvantages to using layoutSubviews and then programmatically positioning the controls instead of just applying constraints to the controls when they are created?

In my case I have a view with 80 UILabels that get positioned and sized equally in a 16x5 grid

I did have a working view made with interface builder but there were a LOT of constraints to get the layout I wanted and it slowed down the entire view controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line - do what's fast. I'd tend toward the programmatic approach in something like that. Then again, you'd probably be better off doing a CollectionView, and letting the layout be handled by that. The FlowLayout will handle a grid no problem.